# Issues in Adaptive card design in Microsoft bot framework

Tags: node.js, typescript

We are using Microsoft bot framework V3 and typescript and while designing Adaptive cards  design below issues are facing
1.Card rendering is failing at UI side When we use "width": "80px" or width:1 for alignment.

2. Red color is not properly displaying("color": "Attention") whichi is coming as brick red

{

```
'contentType': 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
'content': {
    '$schema': 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
    'type': 'AdaptiveCard',
    'version': '1.0',
    'body': [
      {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "separator": true,
            "columns": [

                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "style": "emphasis",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "spacing": "Small",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "color": "Dark",
                            "text": "Company",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "spacing": "Small",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "color": "Dark",
                            "text": "PO Number",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "spacing": "Small",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "color": "Dark",
                            "text": "Status",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "80px"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "style": "emphasis",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "spacing": "Small",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "ABC.COM",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "spacing": "Small",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "200123456",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "spacing": "Small",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "canceled",
                            "wrap": true,
                            "color": "Attention"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

};